# Uncaught syntax error when using ES-6 import syntax in Chrome

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

this is the first time I'm using modules. I've read some tutorials and googled all over but haven't found a solution to my problem.

I have these files with the following code:

**index.html**

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/fight.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="~/js/queue.js"></script>
```

**fight.js**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    import { test } from './queue.js';
    console.log(test);
})
```

**queue.js**

```
export let test = 'queue file has loaded';
```

And I get this error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'*

I'm using live server from Visual Studio, Chrome 83.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: import dont work inside `{...}`

Comment: what you look for is 'dynamic imports' check here for more info in this topic: https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it should be and make sure to import jQuery as well unless you've removed for brevity because `$(document).ready` wont work

```js
import { test } from "./queue.js";
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log(test);
});
```

Comment: yes, i skipped jq import for brevity. Moving import above worked. Thanks a million!

Comment: You click the check mark on the left of answer so that it can be considered as closed. Thanks.